Evaluating an Integral Involving the Exponential Integral Function
I'm working on an integral that involves the Exponential Integral function $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$. The integral is given by:\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ei}(-x)\left(1-xb\right)^{-(a+1)}~dx
\end{equation}
where $\operatorname{Ei}(-x) = \int^{x}_{-\infty}\frac{e^t}{t}~dt$ and $x$ is positive real value and the constants $a$ and $b$ postive real values

Mathematica  and Maple can compute this integral.

Thanks for the response, I prefer to solve it manually and unfortunately i dont know how to use these softwares.

This integral does not converge.

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ei}(-x)\left(1\color{red}{+}xb\right)^{-(a+1)}~dx$ with $a>0, b>0$ has a solution but not OP's variant.

So can a variable transformation be done to solve this like $x=-u$ to make it similar to that $(1+xb)$ or it doesn't matter as long as the integral doesn't converge. Could you please also share the link for solution of the this relation you mentioned that has positive sign instead of the minus  sign.

MSE_Q4959568
